# type observable of t is not assignable to t

Tags: angular

I get the following error in Angular when I try to copy the result of the http service into variable products. Any ideas please? I think this might be related to the mapping, which I'm unsure how to do.

Btw I want to use HttpClient, not Http, and the mapping should be done automatically by using the get("api/route"); syntax, right?

```
Error  TS2322  (TS) Type 'Observable<Product[]>' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.   Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<Product[]>'.
```

Here is the code:

```
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import { Product } from "./product";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";



@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public products: Product[] = [];


    loadProducts(): Observable<Product[]>  {
        debugger;
        this.products = this.http.get<Product[]>("/api/products");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The previous version, that worked, without typesafety, is (just for the record):

...

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public products = [];

     loadProducts() {
        return this.http.get("/api/products")

            .map((data: any[]) => {                               
                this.products = data;
                return true;                 
            });
    }
}
```

I am interested to make the example with type safety work, for this of course Product is defined in a .ts file like this:

```
export interface Product {
    id: number;
    category: string;
    size: string;
   //...
}
```

and I made sure the properties returned from the api match the properties from the interface.

Comment: i dont see you ever subscribed to observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loadProducts` method expects `Observable<Product[]>` to be returned, so all that you need is just follow this rule, for example, like this:

```
loadProducts(): Observable<Product[]>  {
  return this.http.get<Product[]>("/api/products");
}
```

And notice, that `HTTP` request returns an `Observable` in your case, that means, that `this.products = this.http.get<Product[]>("/api/products");` will store an `Observable` type to `this.products`, not `Product[]` as you expected.

**EDIT**

*"I really need to store the result of the api call inside that variable of type Product[] so I need to know how to make the conversion from Observable"*

If I'm not mistaken, you can do that using `take(n)`, which will take last `n` arguments from `Observable` and will `unsubscribe` automatically, in your case you can use `take(1)`. Then, you have to handle returned `Observable` using `.subscribe` as below:

```
loadProducts(): Observable<Product[]>  {
  const responseSubscription: Observable<Product[]> =  this.http.get<Product[]>("/api/products");
  responseSubscription
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(products => this.products = products);
  return responseSubscription;
}
```

Comment: Hello CommercialSuicide, thank you. I really need to store the result of the api call inside that variable of type Product[] so I need to know how to make the conversion from Observable<Product[]>

Comment: @dear1, Hi, I have updated my answer, but I can misspelled or get some issues with types, because I haven't my IDE now to check that. So feel free to ask

Comment: It was a big adventure but it finally worked, you are amazing. thank you. I had to add import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'; for the take to be recognised. Have a great day.

Comment: @dear1, right, you should import every rxjs operator which you're using. Glad to help, good luck with coding ;)

Comment: the type Product defined in C# returned by the api matches the interface in typescript also called Product (properties have the same name). If they didn't, and I had to map, say, CategoryName from Product from the api with category from typescript, can this be easily done? Or is it a convention for the two to share exact same properties and prop names and any processing to be done separately?

Comment: @dear1m it's not absolutely necessary, to provide the same types on server-side and client-side. I usually define typescript types, which I use in the app itself, not what I get from API. And I usually return `Observable<any>` from methods with API calls, and give types only after formatting data. It's my way, you can choose any other